# When using SignalR how does my Web Server know where localhost is?

Tags: javascript, c#, server, client, signalr

I am using **SignalR** in a web application that is hosted on a separate server that has nothing to do with the client.

In the code, I have a function that connects to a **SignalR Self-Hosted Service** (**C#**) that is running on the **client's** computer who is clicking / doing things on the web application (it has been installed by the client). If the client clicks a certain button on my web application, then my service will get data sent to it from the JavaScript code since my server is running on **http://*:8080**.

Everything *appears* to be working fine. My question is, **how**?

My web application is setting the connection in the **Server Side JS Code** to say this

**MyWebApp.cshtml**

```
//Set the hubs URL for the connection
$.connection.hub.url = "http://localhost:8080/signalr";
```

My C# Service running on the client's computer in the background (that has been installed) is saying this:

**MyService.cs**

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
    eventLog1.WriteEntry("Service started");
    //string url = "http://localhost:8080";
    string url = "http://*:8080";
    SignalR = WebApp.Start(url);
    eventLog1.WriteEntry("Server running on " + url);
}
```

How is it possible that they are even communicating when the server side code is saying "Hey look for **localhost** on **8080**!"

And the service says "Hey start on ***:8080**!" ( I don't even understand what * means)

Last but not least, if I uncomment the line in my service that is currently commented out and use that to start the service it will not work! Why will my service start up on **http//*:8080** but **not** on http://localhost:8080 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code:

```
WebApp.Start("http://*:8080")
```

Says *"listen for connections on port 8080 on any IP address available"*. So it will bind to `localhost` (127.0.0.1) and any other assigned IP addresses the machine has. It is basically a wildcard binding.

This code:

```
$.connection.hub.url = "http://localhost:8080/signalr";
```

Says the server is on localhost which resolves to 127.0.0.1.

For your last point as to why it doesn't work if the server started on `http://localhost:8080`, I assume this is because SignalR is having trouble mapping to the correct IP address. Try using `http://127.0.0.1:8080` instead.

Comment: What about "last but not least" part of question?

Comment: Oh, the bit that was added after I answered?

Comment: Thanks @DavidG I am fairly new to allot of these concepts. I am a Desktop Dev transitioning to the Web world. My concern is this: assume that I have 7 computers connected to the same network. If a Computer (client) clicks something on my Web App, will all of the services running on those 7 computers be triggered or / receieve data? or will the WebApp.Start only listen for the localhost on that unique computer causing no conflicts. Does my question make sense? Also remember that I have 7 different services running. So each computer would have its own instance of that service running

Comment: @Yusha Well that's a different question. I can't answer that as it depends on your code. Try it out and see how it works is all I can say.

Comment: I see what you are saying. I will have to do some more testing.